# Azure Stream Analytics - How to sort event hub data based on Timestamp and custom Id fields

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to sort the event hub input data using Stream Analytics and populating the output in ADLS 2 in CSV format but the data is not sorted.

I used azure function (Timer trigger) which fetches the data from SQL Server sequentially (**order by Id field**) and sending the batch event data to event hub.

In Stream Analytics, I am using the event hub stream as Input and the ADLS 2 as output.

I tried both, **CollectTop()** and **TopOne()** to sort the data.

Also, I am using  "TIMESTAMP BY SeenTime"

Below is the ASA query:

eventdata: Input

adls2: Output

```
With 
    Step1 as (   
        SELECT eventdata.Id as Id, eventdata.ClientMacAddress, eventdata.SeenEpoch, 
        eventdata.SeenTime, System.Timestamp() t   
        FROM eventdata
        TIMESTAMP BY SeenTime
    ),
    Step2 as (
        SELECT TopOne() OVER (ORDER BY Id asc) as topEvent  
    FROM Step1 
    Group by TumblingWindow(minute, 10)
    )
    SELECT udf.convertJsonToString(topEvent)
        INTO
        [adls2]
    FROM Step2
```

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: If I'm reading that query correctly, you're getting only 1 record per window. Are you saying that record is not the smallest id (TopOne ORDER BU Id ASC) of that window? Can you confirm Id is of types bigint/float/datetime (which are the only supported types here, as per the [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/collecttop-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json)). Also have you tried to match the LIMIT DURATION to the window (10min)?

Comment: Thanks Florian for your response.
Yes, Id is of type BigInt. No I have not tried LIMIT DURATION.
Also what I am currently doing is sending out the random number of events every 1 minute and its in order by Id asc.
Now the same sequence should be there in ASAL for every 10 minutes tumbling window and pushing to ADLS 2.
Hope you able to understand my query!

Comment: With that TOPONE() you'll get only 1 record per 10 minutes. That's what I'm not understanding. Could you please update the query to one that returns the entire dataset you're expecting? Thanks!